# Office 365 Video Service Not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, media-streaming

I have a developer subscription for Office 365, where I am trying to set up Office 365 Video service.

On accessing the Office 365 Video site `https://TENANT.sharepoint.com/portals/hub/_layouts/15/PointPublishing.aspx?app=video&p=l` it throws a blank page.

Also if I try to navigate to the Video Channel Settings of the video portal under SharePoint it doesn't take me anywhere.

[image]

[image]
`Is there any SharePoint site/web feature that needs to be activated or is it an issue with the subscription.`

Please note I am able to access the settings page from `https://TENANT.sharepoint.com/portals/hub/_layouts/15/settings.aspx`.

Is there anything I am missing here, because I thought video service came pertty much ready for use. Please note I got the office 365 developer subscription activated in August, 2016.

**Update -**
My permission on the site are as below
[image]